# Tried formatting USB to NTFS and now I can no longer mount it or format it

Tags: mount, ntfs, format

I recently formatted my USB drive to NTFS using the command terminal however since then I am unable to mount the USB to my pc and when I try to reformat the USB it says that the permissions are set to read only. Can anybody help me with this?

```
"Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/fabio/USB DISK: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/fabio/USB DISK"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: Can only open '/dev/sdc1' as read-only
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details."
```

Answer (score 1):

this error happens a.o. when a file transfer was not completed when disk got removed or computer shutdown.

You could try to run

```
sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdc1
```

It should automatically correct the wrong volume metadata

Comment: Why do u want to use NTFSProgs when NTFS-3g is installed by default??. Also NTFSProgs is outdated and has been merged with NTFS-3g.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my USB drive had a read-only switch that I'd left activated. I flicked the switch over to read-write mode, power cycled the drive and then I could mount read-write again.

Answer (score 0):

When I have problems of this type I find a Mac somewhere and do a FAT format on the USB flash drive with the Mac.